# Sumar columnas 'alias' en fila con Postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
nombre           nit    colum_alias1    colum_alias2    total_alias
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
nombre1           1      1,500            3,000           ? 
nombre2           2      2,000            4,000           ? 
--------------------------------------------------------------------    
total_columns_alias       ?                 ?             ?
```

LLevo dandole vueltas a esta consulta, me gustaria me ayudaran a decifrar el codigo para poder sumar la consulta anterior de las columnas alias y lograr generar otra consulta y obtener asi, los totales por columnas y por filas.
lo intente con CUBE Y ROLLUP Y CROSSTAB. gracias

Comment: Bien la edicion, pero entonces el asunto?

Answer (score 1):

te adjunto el SQL Fiddle, esto es digamos mas complejo de realizar en SQL, lo apropiado seria escribir un paquete PL/SQL para agregar mas flexibilidad al programa.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9f2ba/15

Comment: Gracias, entiendo tu sugerencia, pero ya me forme la idea de como

Comment: puede ser para tablas mas grandes, solo falto sumar la columna de totales. te agradezco la explicacion

Comment: Podria crear una funcion en pl/sql y mejorar la respuesta y salida de la consulta

Comment: te olvidaste que las columnas son alias de una consulta (a1, a2 y column?) y salen de hacer calculos con otras columnas.

Comment: Select nombre, campo1 as 'cta1', campo2 as 'cta2', QuieroSumar(cta1+cta2) from Tabla. En tu ejemplo a1y a2 son campos fisicos no resultado de consulta, qdamos como al comienzo, no soluciona mi pregunta?

Comment: Todos los alias son nombres de consulta

Comment: era solo una idea de como se puede solucionar el problema, no suministraste información adicional como estructuras de tablas, etc. Igualmente, esa consulta se puede adaptar, lo que esta después de. **with** son sub-queries.